# How to Solve Understatr: "Invalid char in json text error?"

Tags: r, web-scraping, jsonlite

I scraped data from understat using R a few days ago and it worked just fine and was able to scrape the stats I was looking for, and i exported them into the project directory for more accessibility. I try again, in a different project, a couple of days after and it doesn't work at all.

For example if I scrape using this function: get_player_seasons_stats(player_id = x) it returns "invalid char in json text."
I've loaded jsonlite and curl just to make sure everything was in place but it still returns the same error message no matter what. Here's a reprex:

```r
remotes::install_github('ewenme/understatr')
#> Downloading GitHub repo ewenme/understatr@HEAD
#> Running `R CMD build`...
#> * checking for file 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUHlVek\remotes4e607ff3b75\ewenme-understatr-dd6e48f/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
#> * preparing 'understatr':
#> * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
#> * checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
#> * checking for empty or unneeded directories
#> Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
#> * building 'understatr_1.0.1.9000.tar.gz'
#> Installing package into 'C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2'
#> (as 'lib' is unspecified)
library(understatr)

get_player_seasons_stats(player_id = 882)
#> Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
#>                                        NA
#>                      (right here) ------^
```

Previously, the function returned a dataframe I could work with. I tried removing and installing tidyverse again but had no luck with that.

If I also try to get available leagues too, R is unable to scrape data at all, resulting in an empty tibble here:

```r
library(understatr)

#available leagues
leagues <- get_leagues_meta()

head(leagues, n = 2)
#> # A tibble: 0 × 0
```

I wanted to know is someone has ever had this problem and how they solved it.

Comment: Hello, Jeffrey, it appears to be a common issue se [here](https://github.com/ewenme/understatr/issues/18) and [here](https://github.com/ewenme/understatr/issues/12)

Comment: That's a shame. I tried again but this time with the WorldFootballR package too and no luck. So maybe I'd have to wait and see if it gets resolved. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Perhaps you can line run the source code of [get_leagues_meta](https://github.com/ewenme/understatr/blob/dd6e48fb3b86174b9346e9b08a821045c9415d4d/R/leagues.R#L49) and [get_leagues_seasons](https://github.com/ewenme/understatr/blob/dd6e48fb3b86174b9346e9b08a821045c9415d4d/R/leagues.R#L8). The home_url variable in this package is  https://understat.com/

Comment: Appears to use `rvest` and `tidyverse` packages.